# Unable to get current page id(published) wordpress localhost

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get current page id inside my custom plugin but no matter what I try I get null or false as result here is dump of my $wp_query, and I get there in_the_loop false maybe that's the reason I am unable to get the data of Page,
my dump

```
/srv/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/blueprint/partials/helpers.php:5:
object(WP_Query)[553]
  public 'query' => null
  public 'query_vars' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'tax_query' => null
  public 'meta_query' => boolean false
  public 'date_query' => boolean false
  public 'queried_object' => null
  public 'queried_object_id' => null
  public 'request' => null
  public 'posts' => null
  public 'post_count' => int 0
  public 'current_post' => int -1
  public 'in_the_loop' => boolean false
  public 'post' => null
  public 'comments' => null
  public 'comment_count' => int 0
  public 'current_comment' => int -1
  public 'comment' => null
  public 'found_posts' => int 0
  public 'max_num_pages' => int 0
  public 'max_num_comment_pages' => int 0
  public 'is_single' => boolean false
  public 'is_preview' => boolean false
  public 'is_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_archive' => boolean false
  public 'is_date' => boolean false
  public 'is_year' => boolean false
  public 'is_month' => boolean false
  public 'is_day' => boolean false
  public 'is_time' => boolean false
  public 'is_author' => boolean false
  public 'is_category' => boolean false
  public 'is_tag' => boolean false
  public 'is_tax' => boolean false
  public 'is_search' => boolean false
  public 'is_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_comment_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_trackback' => boolean false
  public 'is_home' => boolean false
  public 'is_privacy_policy' => boolean false
  public 'is_404' => boolean false
  public 'is_embed' => boolean false
  public 'is_paged' => boolean false
  public 'is_admin' => boolean false
  public 'is_attachment' => boolean false
  public 'is_singular' => boolean false
  public 'is_robots' => boolean false
  public 'is_favicon' => boolean false
  public 'is_posts_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_post_type_archive' => boolean false
  private 'query_vars_hash' => boolean false
  private 'query_vars_changed' => boolean true
  public 'thumbnails_cached' => boolean false
  private 'stopwords' => null
  private 'compat_fields' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'query_vars_hash' (length=15)
      1 => string 'query_vars_changed' (length=18)
  private 'compat_methods' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'init_query_flags' (length=16)
      1 => string 'parse_tax_query' (length=15)
```

I am outside wp loop maybe that's why I cant get it but how will be able to get that data. Moreover, It's just a random page on localhost that when I view I cant see page data.

my code

```
<?php
add_action('init','newFunction');
function newFunction(){
  global $wp_query;
 var_dump($wp_query);
 // Do your code here
}
```

[image: My page that I view]

Basically I have to get current page's ID so whenever someone uses my plugin their page ID will be accessible to my plugin.
I need page id to check whether current page id exists in my list of page id's
If yes then on that page i Will render my plugin

Comment: What & where are the purpose and use of page ID, in the backend or in frontend? and you only need page ID or any post type ID?

Comment: I need page id to check whether current page id exists in my list of page id's 
If yes then on that page i Will render my plugin.
I've updated question with above lines too,

Comment: Ok, but you didn't tell, you're taking about the backend page or the frontend page? and what your plugin renders? can you describe that as well?

Comment: yes I forgot to mention about that, I want it  on frontend page

Comment: then you can use [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function for all the checking, doesn't need to do things with `$wp_query`